# Handling java types

Tags: java

Does java really handle all primitive types differently than custom Objects? I pose this question as I   examined and tried to "interpret" the results of this simple experimental program:

```
public class RandomObject {

 String name;
 int value;

public RandomObject(String s, int i){
setName(s);
setValue(i);
}

public int getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
this.value = value;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
 }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

int x = 2;
int y = x;
System.out.println(y);
x = 4;
System.out.println(y);


RandomObject obj1 = new RandomObject("object1", 4);
RandomObject obj2;

obj2 = obj1;

System.out.println(obj2.getValue());
obj1.setValue(17);
System.out.println(obj2.getValue());

 }
```

The results are: 
2
2
4
17

Although x has changed, the value of y remains immutable, whereas in objects the change affects both of them.
Does the same happen in all primitive types (other than integers) and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java *does* treat the values stored in the `y` and `obj2` variables at the point that they are assigned (`y = x` and `obj2 =`obj1` respectively) similarly, but the key difference is that with Objects the variable only contains a *reference* to an actual object, not the data-values themselves.

```
int x,y;
x = 2;
y = x; //x = 2, y = 2
x = 3; //x = 3, y = 2 - Changing x does not change y

Object a,b;
a = new MyObject("foo"); //Create Object O on the heap, a = [Address of Object O]
b = a; //a = [Address of Object O], b = [Address of Object O]
a.updateValue("barr"); //Update a property of Object O
//a and b still contain [Address of Object O], but Object O has a new value.
a = new MyObject("Bazz"); //Create Object P, a = [Address of Object P]
//a = [Address of Object P], b = [Address of Object O]
```

The key thing to note is that the variables only get updated when there is an assignment (`=`) statement.

Comment: I have to admit, this is a quite illustrative explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, variables which are any type of object, only contain a reference (pointer), to the data they represent. When you assign obj2 to obj1 you are saying:

> take the address in obj2 and put it in obj1.

when you use the dot operator "." you are saying

> The object at that address, give me that object.

Variables which are any type of primitive actually store the data themselves. So when you say

```
int i = 2;
int j = 3;

j = i;
```

> Store the value 2 in j

Answer (score 0):

You are just assigning `Obj1 to Obj2`  Assignment will be same for both. The concept of `Immutable` comes in picture when you try to change the value.

Example below:

```
    String one = "String";
    String two = one;
    System.out.println("equal: " + one.equals(two));
    System.out.println("same:  " + (one == two));
    // Change one
    one = one.concat("concat");
    System.out.println("equal: " + one.equals(two));
    System.out.println("same:  " + (one == two));
```

It outputs

```
equal: true
same:  true
equal: false
same:  false
```

Because `String` is `immutable` every operation on `String` creates new `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RandomObject obj1 = new RandomObject("object1", 4);
```

This assignment first creates an object of `RandomObject` and assigns its reference to `obj1`.

```
obj2 = obj1;
```

Now `obj1` and `obj2` both reference the same object.Any operation run on `obj1` will reflect to the created object, which simultaneously being refered by `obj2`.Hence `obj2` will also show the side effect of any operation on `obj1` that directly or indirectly tampers the object created.

However removing reference of `obj1` like `obj1=null` wont affect `obj2` because the reference has been changed and only `obj2` is now pointing to the created object.

[More Info Here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=147)